# centering tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, plot

I have some problems concerning the command `\centering`. I want to put a `tikzpicture` in the center of the page but I can't do it. I tried with `\centering` and with `\begin{center}...\end{center}` but nothing happened.
I have also a problem with axis: I want to resize them but I don't know how to do it. Thank you in advance.
The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}  
[scale=2.5,axis lines=middle,  
enlargelimits,  
xtick={0,1.57,3.14,6.28},ytick={0.5,1},  
xticklabels={0,$\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$, $2\pi$},  
yticklabels={$1/2$, $1$},  
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis equal]  
\addplot  
[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=100,thick,blue]  
{(sin(deg(x)))^2+cos(deg(x))};  
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your scaling is too large and besides that, the margins left and right are not the same by default.

Comment: You should know that `\begin{center}...\end{center}` adds some vertical space which might not be wanted. (Off-topic for the real issue). Please don't ask more than one question per post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `showframe` shows the issue -- the margins are not same on the left and right side. Using `geometry` this can be repaired, the given values are just guesses.

I did not address the axis scaling 'sub'question

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for showing the margins
\begin{document}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}  
[scale=2.5,axis lines=middle,  
enlargelimits,  
xtick={0,1.57,3.14,6.28},ytick={0.5,1},  
xticklabels={0,$\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$, $2\pi$},  
yticklabels={$1/2$, $1$},  
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis equal]  
\addplot  
[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=100,thick,blue]  
{(sin(deg(x)))^2+cos(deg(x))};  
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

[image]